How to enumerate Hamiltonian paths accounting for symmetry?
I've been working on a project with lattice and Hamiltonian paths, trying to replicate findings from these papers (not sure if they're copyrighted)
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/27/18/030
https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/93/8/5967/222940/Enumeration-of-all-compact-conformations-of
My end goal is to get to 103,346 which is the number of Hamiltonian paths unrelated by symmetry for a 3x3x3 cube. I know the naive solutions with BFS/DFS/Backtracking, but because of the scale of these graphs, and the goals of my project that's suboptimal, so I'm trying to do this algorithm, but not sure how to account for symmetries.
Here's my current code, (I'm assuming it's a level order BFS where you can apply permutations and prune at each level)
def bfs(x, y, z):
    # Initialize parameters
    l, m, n = 2, 2, 2
    N = l * m * n
    dirs = [(1, 0, 0), (-1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, -1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, -1)]

    # Helper lambda functions
    number_node = lambda x, y, z: x + l * y + l * m * z
    is_valid = lambda x, y, z: 0 <= x < l and 0 <= y < m and 0 <= z < n

    queue = [((x, y, z) , [number_node(x, y, z)])]

    # Level Order BFS
    for i in range(N): # instead of while q:
        # Eliminate symmetries?
        for i in range(len(queue)):
            node, path = queue.pop(0)
            if len(path) == N:
                # print(path)
                yield path
            for dx, dy, dz in dirs:
                x, y, z = node
                nx, ny, nz = x + dx, y + dy, z + dz
                next_node = number_node(nx, ny, nz)
                if is_valid(nx, ny, nz) and next_node not in path:
                    queue.append(((nx, ny, nz), path + [next_node]))

def main():
    l, m, n = 2, 2, 2
    def all_bfs():
        for x in range(l):
            for y in range(m):
                for z in range(n):
                    yield from bfs(x, y, z)
    gen = all_bfs()
    output = list(gen)
    print(output, len(output))

Here's an important excerpt from the paper.
We wish to enumerate the different paths which completely break all of the symmetries.
First, we must enumerate all of the symmetries. Consider all of the vertices of the graph to
be numbered consecutively. Any transformation (e.g. rotation, mirror inversion, etc.) can be
expressed as a permutation of these indices. The number of transformations, and therefore
permutations, is calculated as follows in terms of the number of ways a d-dimensional
hypercube can be reoriented: (i) we first have the symmetry by the number of comers of
the cube (2^d); (ii) next, once we choose a corner to fix, we have d! ways to choose how
we mange the edges (for example, for d = 3, we have three ways to place the first edge,
leaving two ways to place the second). Thus, there are d!2^d transformations for a simple
hypercubic lattice in d dimensions.
To generate the starting paths, we traverse the tree and compare sub-branches for
symmetries. At each node, we transform the trajectories formed by each sub-branch
using all of the enumerated transformations (i.e. applying all of the permutations). If any
transformation can map one sub-branch into another, than the sub-branches are related by
symmetry, and we can discard one of them. The remaining sub-branches themselves will
now be enumerated using the same procedure. If none of the sub-branches are related by
symmehy, and if all of the d!2^d symmetries have been broken by the current path, then the
current path is a starting path, and we can backtrack and continue the enumeration with the
unexplored branches.
For example, consider a walker starting from the corner of a cube. It is at the top of the
tree of Hamiltonian walks. It now has three possible paths, but each path can be transformed
into the other by a mirror symmetry. Thus, we can discard two of the sub-branches, choose
the third, and continue the process. When none of the sub-branches of a given node are
related by symmetry, then each sub-branch is a starting path. Then the walker backs up
one level of the tree in order to traverse through the sub-branches left behind.
The enumeration of all of the walks and the enumeration of the starting paths are deeply
related. Each traverse the ideal tree, only differing when the walk has completed and when
sub-branches are to be discarded.
Any help is appreciated.

Do you have a specific question in mind ? Also, I don't thinks everyone has access to scientific papers
